# Examples of web sites created with Microsoft Publisher 2010

Tags: microsoft-publisher

Does anyone know of web sites that have been created with Microsoft Publisher 2010?  I'd like links so that I can examine them and see if Publisher is a good way to create a web site.

Comment: Most of the time WYSIWYG editors don't produce particularly good pages, HTML has too many oddities and multiple ways to achieve the same thing, with advantages and disadvantages in certain situations, that make doing it "right" algorithmically exceedingly difficult.

Answer (score 2):

[www.crabbygeezer.com](http://www.crabbygeezer.com)